# IE ColorBox Scroll Bar Not Showing Up

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, scrollbar

I am using a colorbox modal on the "SAMPLE SAVINGS" Link and the Scroll Bar is not showing up for users with IE 8. Also the same users see "Javascript jQuery errors".

I'm not sure how to target for this browser specific error. Anyone know?

I this is the page I am working on currently (please take a look in IE):
http://whiterhino.us/aspire_setup/

CLICK "Sample Savings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a message in my Google Chrome debug console saying 'Jquery is not defined' on line 4 of jquery.colorbox.js